# Is there a non-empty intersection between the believers at Acts 2:1-4 and the believers at Acts 4:31?

Tags: acts, referent-identification, pneumatology, chronology

Acts 2:1-4 (ESV):

> When the day of Pentecost arrived, they were all together in one place. 2 And suddenly there came from heaven a sound like a mighty rushing wind, and it filled the entire house where they were sitting. 3 And divided tongues as of fire appeared to them and rested on each one of them. 4 **And they were all filled with the Holy Spirit** and began to speak in other tongues as the Spirit gave them utterance.

Acts 4:31 (ESV):

> And when they had prayed, the place in which they were gathered together was shaken, **and they were all filled with the Holy Spirit** and continued to speak the word of God with boldness.

Were there any believers present at both events?

More generally: can Christians be filled with the Holy Spirit more than once?

*Note: if the set theory terminology used in the title is a bit confusing, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)*

Comment: I love the title of this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer here is, almost certainly because Peter and John (at least!) were present on both occasions, see acts 4:23 and Acts 2:1, 14, etc.

Given this, it is almost certain that, very likely, several other disciples/apostles were also present on both occasions.

**CONCLUSION**

Therefore, there were people present on both occasions in Acts 1, 2 and Acts 4.

**APPENDIX - Holy Spirit Coming Upon People**

If we take the example of Samson, we see a similar phenomenon that the Holy Spirit or the Spirit of the LORD coming powerfully upon him to accomplish a specific task such as:

- Judges 14:6 - and the Spirit of the LORD came powerfully upon him, and he tore the lion apart with his bare hands as one would tear a young goat
- Judges 14:19 - Then the Spirit of the LORD came mightily upon him, and he went down to Ashkelon, killed thirty of their men, took their apparel, and gave their clothes to those who had solved the riddle.
- Judges 15:14 - When Samson arrived in Lehi, the Philistines came out shouting against him. And the Spirit of the LORD came mightily upon him. The ropes on his arms became like burnt flax, and the bonds broke loose from his hands.

Saul had similar experiences:

- 1 Sam 10:10 - When Saul and his servant arrived at Gibeah, a group of prophets met him. Then the Spirit of God rushed upon him, and he prophesied along with them.
- 1 Sam 11:6 - When Saul heard their words, the Spirit of God rushed upon him, and he burned with great anger.
- 1 Sam 19:23 - So Saul went to Naioth in Ramah. But the Spirit of God came upon even Saul, and he ...

Thus, we even have OT precedents where the Spirit of the LORD, or the Holy Spirit comes powerfully upon a person more than once.